# How do I calculate temperature diffusion in a gas contained in a heatsink?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, temperature

To simplify the problem, consider a sphere with a diameter of $25\mathrm{mm}$ inside an infinite heatsink at $300\mathrm{K}$.

At $t=0$ I instantaneously raise the temperature of the gas in the interior by $10\mathrm{mK}$ - how long does it take for the overall gas temperature to drop back to within $1\mathrm{mK}$ of the walls?

I am not sure how to approach this, since it does not seem that the gas would lose heat by either convection or radiation in an efficient manner.

Experimentally, it would appear that the time is less than one second, but my measurements are around the background noise level so I am not confident they are correct.

Comment: I've approximated it using Fourier's Law and the time does seem to be in low seconds, which is good enough for me to put some faith in the lack of measurement.

Comment: Seems like you already figured this out with Fourier's law, which is probably what I would have done (assuming only conductive heat transfer, but I'm not sure if that's appropriate). Can you post your calculation as an answer? I'd like to read it.

Comment: @DanielSank It was "back of envelope stuff" 6 months ago as part of a big ongoing project. It was "good enough" and any problems with this in the experiment can be fixed (or discovered) by altering gas flow rates.

Comment: Ok, well, in that case since you posted a comment indicating that you solved the problem *less than an hour after posting the question itself*, I don't think this post is a good example of an applied question which was wrongfully ignored.

Comment: @DanielSank I "solved" the problem using Fourier's Law to the extent that I felt I could ignore timings. At that time I had no idea whether my calculation was accurate or appropriate in the context. So I went with my data that suggested Fourier was ballpark correct.

Comment: Ok, so, what would you expect other users to do in this situation? I see this post and I see that the poster (you) figured out an approximate solution in less than an hour after posting. To me, that says "move on, this guy's fine". If you had added that information to the post (use the edit button) and then asked a specific question about, say, the accuracy of your approximation, I bet you would have gotten a response.

Comment: Well, in all of these question what I would like to see is "I did something like this and it worked/failed".